# Solr sort search using AND operator first and then results from OR operator

Tags: search, solr, operators

Let's say that I have a phrase like:

> Cyclone Winston Fiji Relief Appeal

and first I want to display the all words in it results, so basically an AND search, and after that do display all results that have at least one word in it, so an OR search.

Is it possible, and how would this should be done?

So first I'll see the results like:

> Cyclone Winston Fiji Relief Appeal
>   Appeal for Cyclone Winston Fiji Relief
>   Appeal for Fiji Relief Cyclone Winston
>  
>   ...

and then results like:

> Cyclon
>   Widston
>   Appeal
>   Fiji
>   ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr (Lucene actually) do not have AND and OR commands - they are in-reality MUST, SHOULD, and NOT for each term. And what you said should match to the standard SHOULD use case, which is what happens when you don't do anything special. The most terms match, the more relevant it is.

So, if you are not getting that, something else is a problem. You can enable debugging to see what actually happens (though it takes time to understand the output). One scenario is that you are using eDisMax and searching across multiple fields with matches coming from different sources. Then only the best field match is used and other matches are shadowed. Using the **tie** parameter can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't happy with the current relevance mechanism, you can improve it boosting the content by proximity.
Using eDismax, you're looking for **pf** and **ps** parameters as explained in [this wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser).
For instance if you are querying a field called *text*, your query would look like:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/<YOUR_COLLECTION>/select?defType=edismax&q=Cyclone Winston Fiji Relief Appeal&pf=text&qf=text^3&ps=10
```

Where the phrase query will be boosted by 3 (please choose a weight appropriate for your needs) and  10 is the slop (also here choose your slop).